# When I run cucumber test from Jenkins, it is running twice

Tags: jenkins, cucumber, cucumber-junit

I have 5 feature files and 5 runner files in my cucumber project. And, when I run the project from Jenkins it is running entire test for two times. So, is it possible to run only particular runner file from Jenkins? How to mention a particular runner file to run in "Goal and options" in Jenkins?

Comment: Are you using maven? Try this "mvn clean test -Dtest=xxxxTest"

Comment: Yes, I'm using Maven...
xxxxTest means runner.java file...?

Comment: Yeah that is correct...

Comment: When I use that command it is throwing the error like,
"No plugin found for prefix 'mvn clean test -Dtest=F'"
I have installed maven clean plugin, still it is showing the same error

Comment: Do you also have a runner that runs all the feature files? (As that might explain the fact they're run twice; once from their own runner, once from the general runner)

Comment: @ Marit,
Yes. That is the issue.

Comment: @Marit
Then, How can I make to run only particular runner file...?

Comment: Could you update your question with the code of your runner? If you provide a directory, it will run all features in that directory. If you provide a filename, it will run only that file.

Comment: @Marit 
I have mentioned the feature file name in Jenkins. When I build it, it is going through all the runner files. I have multiple runner files, each for particular feature file and one runner file to run all feature files. So, when I build, it is running from the individual runner file as well as from the runner file which is written to run all feature files. So, How can I make it to run only once...?

Comment: Remove the file that runs them all. (Note that you can also run all your tests by selecting all the feature files / runners in your IDE.)

Comment: That's working fine. But, is there any other way to do this without deleting the runner file?